# Loading the same image multiple times

Tags: html

Assuming I load the same image in different places inside the html file like:

```
<img src="image.png">
```

and after some code I load it again. That means it'll take html double effort to load the images? If yes is there any way to pre-load the image and then use it as many times as I want without re-loading it?

Thanks in advance for your answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not preload the image, but you can add the image using JavaScript's `appendChild()` method to put it wherever you want.

```js
var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = 'http://placekitten.com/g/200/300';
document.body.appendChild(image1);
```

Answer (score 7):

If they have the same real path, then browser will cache them.

Comment: Its depends on cache headers :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, but i hope evil anti cache headers aren't commonly used for pictures.